# Hexagonal Architecture - Should I put repository interface in the Domain Layer or Application Layer

Tags: hexagonal-architecture

I can't find the ultimate answer for hexagonal architecture.

The question is in the title.

Should I put the repository interface in the Domain Layer or Application Layer ?
Both seems to be correct but what is the main difference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has nothing to do with hexagonal architecture, but with DDD. And according to DDĎ, the repository interface bekongs to the domain model.  As a direct client of the domain, application layer calls the methods on repository interface.